# sololearn says code is wrong, python tutor says otherwise

Tags: python-3.x, type-conversion

I'm trying to learn python through sololearn in the mobile app but somehow the app only accepts its own codes or mine is wrong. If I run the code on pythontutor the code gives the desired output but sololearn keeps saying the code is wrong. The question has to convert an input to an integer in order to multiply it by a string and give a concatenated output

this is my code:

```
x = input()
y = int(input())

z = x * y
```

[but sololearn says my answer is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y1D9.jpg)

[?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwC2O.jpg)

[this is the pythontutor page where I had a supposedly successful output](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=x%20%3D%20input%28%29%0Ay%20%3D%20int%28input%28%29%29%0A%0Az%20%3D%20x%20*%20y&cumulative=false&curInstr=3&h)

Comment: You're never printing `z`.  If SoloLearn is expecting printed output, you need `print(z)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sololearn expects you to print your output, so that they can read it and check if it is correct:

```
x = input()
y = int(input())

z = x * y

print(z)
```

Comment: oh yeah, sorry about that I always forget. Thanks bud!

Comment: Gladly! If my answer is correct, feel free to click the check mark.